# Xcode, Duplicate symbol _main

Tags: xcode

I have duplicate symbol _main.

The problem is it says "Duplicate symbol _main in /Users/.../i386/main-B9843B6026D6EFA4.o and /Users/.../i386/main-B9843B6026D6EFA4.o", the XXX and XXX are actually the same .o file. I don't know why it thinks it's duplicate symbol when it's the same .o?!

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This can happen if there are multiple occurrences of main() function.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Ah..I figure out it's that I have multiple entries under Targets/Compiled Sources ( in newer XCode it's under Build Phases/Compile Sources ). I removed them and the problem is solved. The multiple entry thing probably has to do with Git merge.

Comment: I still dont have mine figured out... any other ideas anyone?

Comment: you really saved my lots of efforts

Comment: I had a duplicate main from TBXML (which I just added)

Comment: Thanks! If only I could give you more points... I'm starting to get enough of this XCode bullshit!

Comment: This can also happen if you accidentally #import "someFile.m" instead of #import "someFile.h"

Comment: I have had a similar error when i recreated a subclass of NSManagedObject and gave the option to replace instead of just removing the file and recreating. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wow! Lots of effort saved!

Comment: it happened to me when i tried to import some other project code in my project. Xcode added main.m file from imported source code to compile sources for my parent project target. Thanks lot @huggie. you saved lot of time for me.

Comment: I needed to remove main.m because I was rewriting my AppDelegate in Swift

Answer (score 23):

It appeared that in my case I was importing a .m file instead of its .h counterpart.
Solved by editing

```
#import "Tools.m"
```

into

```
#import "Tools.h"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After I tried all other solutions a simple search for .m" in my project showed the import of an .m file.

Comment: I had the same problem after changing around the inheritance hierarchy. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I had multiple file "main.m" in my project. This answer helped me! --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/12989012/1881895

Answer (score 16):

I also had this problem and it was caused by code I imported from another project.
I did a grep for "int main" in my project directory:

```
grep -nr "int main" .
```

and found

```
./main.m:13:int main(int argc, char *argv[])
./IMPORTED_DIR/main.m:13:int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

the IMPORTED_DIR contained the extra main.m that was causing the error for me

I removed that file from the Project -> Targets -> Build phases -> Compile sources list and then it compiled

Comment: i made a search by int main and i had two equal files, I removed one and project run. thank you ;)

Comment: I ran `grep -nr "int main" .` and found a sample project within my project that came in as part of an SDK download that I added. After finding this out, I deleted those files via Xcode and voilà! The project now builds. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue with using two third party framework. (AppLovin and Flurry)
And I came to know that by removing "all_load" from "Other Linker Flags" in build settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem opening a project, that was created with Xcode 4.0.2, with Xcode 4.1. I simply solved by clicking on "Modernize Project" (Editor/Modernize Project). This procedure automatically removed all duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

If still have a problem, try to search like this: "int main(", and remove those files except main.m

Answer (score 2):

Just got this problem myself, but after reading huggie's solution which did lead me on the right track, I was left a bit confused.
So current solution in Xcode:
Choose project, target -> build phases and click validate settings

Then Xcode will auto fix its own mistake. It is always nice when the tools tries to stop your progress ;)

Comment: Where should that be?

Comment: This is awesome, never seen this before. Just go to your project build phases, and you can find `Validate Settings` in Editor menu. Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I declared an NSString in my constants file (imported by many classes) but forgot to define it as static!!

e.g.  `NSString* PARAMS = @"paramA";`
should be: `static NSString* PARAMS = @"paramA";`

Reading the full error message allowed me to figure this out: "Duplicate symbol PARAMS". Don't be afraid and try to understand error messages! Sometimes they might even tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had imported another project, in order to utilize a library contained within. It resulted my project having two main.m files.

This was even more confusing, since the error didn't show up until several builds later.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this for method names too!

I got `duplicate symbol _runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking` after adding DBCamera via CocoaPods and it was because both my category on NSObject (NSObject+Tools.h) and the GPUImage dependency file GPUImageOutput.m both had a method called 'runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking'.

I was fortunate enough to be able to remove my method from code because I wasn't actually using it anymore or anywhere.

It's probably what I deserve for putting a category on NSObject.