# Compile error when integrating Facebook with an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been trying to integrate Facebook with my app to allow users to update their status, but when I try to build I get this error:

> "Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1"

I have followed the steps from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EICTZ7UM4zs) YouTube video, but he hasn't got any issues.

I also get this advise (may be related):

> /Users/Ben/Documents/Apps/Ball Game/MainWindow.xib:10:0 'Ball Game
>   View Controller' has both its 'View' and 'NIB Name' properties set.
>   This configuration is not supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is probably some more to that error message, the compiler should print out the error before it exits. Also I recommend using the newer compiler (LLVM) that has been around some time now. Get the latest version of Xcode and use the latest iOS SDK, you can still deploy for older iOS versions if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much searching around i came across this so answer which is the same issue i was having

[Xcode, Duplicate symbol _main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380972/xcode-duplicate-symbol-main)

the answer is on there and is correct its to do with then i was adding the resources for the fb it already had a test app in the folders and was using a windows main.xib which was conflicting

Anybody else stumbles across this i suggest looking in your resources library.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the NIB/xib file error: When you include controller objects in xib files, you can create their views in the same file (and assign the view you have created to the `view` property of the controller) or you can tell the controller to load its view from a different xib file. You probably want to assign the `view` in the same file, in which case leave the 'NIB Name' blank.