# 3245 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm getting a very long Linker Error when I try to compile my code, with 3245 `duplicate symbol` errors.  The errors always include `main.o` as the first item, and then one of my other classes as the other item.  Obviously, posting the entire error would be pointless (and probably not possible).  It actually takes Xcode a few seconds *just to render the text* of the error... which I find amusing for some reason.  But the gist is this:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewType._device in:
    /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flexile-czlbybfalwraxaawasjobleidvys/Build/Intermediates/Flexile.build/Debug-iphoneos/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o
    /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flexile-czlbybfalwraxaawasjobleidvys/Build/Intermediates/Flexile.build/Debug-iphoneos/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ModelViewController.o
```

Like I said, the first class listed in each error is always `main.o`.  I've tried:

1. I've searched through my project and I can't find a single place where I included/imported `main.m`.
2. I've checked my Compile Sources and nothing is duplicated as far as I can tell. I've got 266 source files, so it's hard to be absolutely sure, but certainly main.m is only included once.
3. I've checked `Other Linker Flags` in `Build Settings` and it's empty.
4. I've cleaned the project and I've deleted all derived data, just in case.

Comment: what's `ModelViewController`?

Comment: It help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380998/1568872

Comment: accidental change to PCH file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: I had imported a ".m" file in one of my classes on accident. Took me a while to find it but that fixed the problem.  Thanks for the suggestions!