# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I am not sure what I have done wrong.
 I moved my project folder to another folder and copied the backup folder to desktop.
 I tried to open the backup project and build, I received the linker error.
So I decided to I delete my backup folder and moved back my project folder to desktop. I can't compile anymore and received the following error.

```
 Showing Recent Issues clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/BRO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFITNESS-flzvwdymttxhducvwvmhpuaqfzhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SFITNESS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SFITNESS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main-90EC778DD760FD57.o
/Users/BRO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFITNESS-flzvwdymttxhducvwvmhpuaqfzhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SFITNESS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SFITNESS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main-F627C2B37F247040.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Help Needed]

## No derived data folder

[image: pic]

## Still the same

**1. I opened Derived Data folder and deleted everything in it**
**2. I deletes all the project in all simulator**
**3. I restarted xCode, Clean and build**

Still the same
    [image: Pic 2]

## Added the project into GitHub

The [link](https://github.com/hansheung/SFITNESS/tree/03225530030e4e5210612b5897bbfe1f7c8482d1)

Comment: have you deleted you driveddata ??

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, never touch the drive data.

Comment: @HansheungCheah delete derivedata than try

Comment: How to delete derivedata?

Comment: /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData delete that folder

Comment: I can't locate this folder

Comment: bro go to user than mac their you find library

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build and building again?

Comment: Chk this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. This might help/

Comment: As your description. I guess the reason is your `library search path` into the setting of the project. just try to edit it.

Comment: Edit what for library search path, can you elaborate a bit more please

Comment: @HansheungCheah Can you attached screenshot of linker flag ?

Comment: Please check, may be you have import .m file except .h file.

Comment: Or check in your libraries _main is duplicated, It should always be one.

Comment: Ah..I figure out it's that I have multiple entries under Targets/Compiled Sources ( in newer XCode it's under Build Phases/Compile Sources ). I removed them and the problem is solved. The multiple entry thing probably has to do with Git merge.

Comment: @HansheungCheah refer this it same as your problem i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380972/xcode-duplicate-symbol-main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add necessary framework to your project. Check all third party party framework and search its required framework for support. For e.g. if you add `google analytic` then you need to `add CoreData` , `Foundation` etc framework. There is some framework is missing for which third party framework needs.

Or you can-

1. Press `"Cmd + Shift + K"` or `shift + cmd + alt + k` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` 
   in terminal
3. Open the project and re-build it

`Linker command failed with exit code 1` - to solve this error press `"Cmd + Shift + K"` or `shift + cmd + alt + k` this will do the work for you. I also have this same issue but solved by using this line . Hope this will solve your problem.

**OUTPUT OF YOUR PROJECT -**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks Rashed, I have tried your solution but it didn't work. Tried many times to delete the DerivedData and restart xCode. It still won't build.

Comment: did you try shift + cmd + alt + k?

Comment: I suspect some files or code that I have downloaded from gitHub which I have added long time ago that was not properly referenced in objective C after I have copy the folder around.

Comment: that will not be a problem

Comment: This answer has been edited to add spam images, and should probably be removed.

Answer (score 5):

```
duplicate symbol _main
```

You have two main.m files and the function main() is in conflict.

[image]

Just delete the main.m under CERangeSlider and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I have cloned your project from github, I found that the `main.m` file  is repeated in `SFITNESS` and `CERangeSlider` 
You may delete one of them and your project will work.

Answer (score 0):

how to get `derived data`

- Open Xcode.
- Open Xcode preferences (`Cmd + ,`)
- Select location option.
- now you have scene, now click on the point as shown in below image.

  [image]
- your derived data is now opened (**suggest you to add drive data in finder left menu**). Delete whatever inside the drive data.
- now delete your project from simulator.
- clean and build your project.

If you are still facing issues then let us know so that we can help accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your step but still the same error?