# xcode clang error

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

My project was Ok but now something happened and i got an error, i haven't change anything.
i use cocos2d also .

I got this :

> ld: duplicate symbol _main in
>   /Users/ranturgeman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BetaDoll-ddteajwutrsqgqfvfeodagynwyal/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d
>   libraries.a(main.o) and
>   /Users/ranturgeman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BetaDoll-ddteajwutrsqgqfvfeodagynwyal/Build/Intermediates/BetaDoll.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BetaDoll.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
>   for architecture i386

**Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1**

What is that ?
I really don't have any duplications in my code .

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: what is formatting ? format what ?

Comment: anyone  please ? i just cant figure it out .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode duplicate symbol _main ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535265/xcode-duplicate-symbol-main)

Comment: no, not possible, first because i have seen that and the solution there wasnt helpful for me, second because as i wrote here, sometimes i get an error and sometimes not, third, because i have not changed anything in my code, so its that xcode bugs that happen to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all your builds folder, clean Xcode cache, and try the Build again.