# C Problem with Compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I just started learning C, and wrote my hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I get a really long error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

 Ld /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug/CProj normal x86_64
        cd /Users/Solomon/Desktop/C/CProj
        setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
        /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CProj.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug/CProj

    ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/helloworld.o and /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64
    Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I am running xCode

Should I reinstall DevTools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried

`int main()`  or even `int main(int argc, char**argv)` ?

Comment: The correct declarations are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or equivalent), but it's unlikely that declaring it as `main()` (which was correct in early versions of C, and likely still accepted by most compilers) would cause that particular error.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the symbol `_main` (which refers to the `main()` function) is defined twice, once in `helloworld.o` and once in `main.o`.

It's likely that you have two source files, `helloworld.c` and `main.c`, in the same project, and that both define a function named `main`.

You can only have one `main` function in a program.  Removing one of those two source files (and the associated object file) from your Xcode project should fix the problem.  (I haven't used Xcode myself; perhaps someone else can tell you how to do that, if it's not obvious.)

(And the correct definition is `int main(void)`, not the old-style `main()`, but I don't think that's related to the symptom you're seeing.)

There are a couple of stackoverflow questions that could be closely related to yours:

- [Xcode duplicate symbol _main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535265/xcode-duplicate-symbol-main)
- [Xcode, Duplicate symbol _main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380972/xcode-duplicate-symbol-main)