# Objective-C categories in static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, categories, static-libraries

Can you guide me how to properly link static library to iPhone project. I use static library project added to app project as direct dependency (target -> general -> direct dependencies) and all works OK, but categories. A category defined in static library is not working in app.

So my question is how to add static library with some categories into other project?

And in general, what is best practice to use in app project code from other projects?

Comment: well, found some answers and seems this question already was answered here (sorry missed it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932856/calling-method-on-category-included-from-iphone-static-library-causes-nsinvalidar)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

**Solution:** As of Xcode 4.2, you only need to go to the application that is linking against the library (not the library itself) and click the project in the Project Navigator, click your app's target, then build settings, then search for "Other Linker Flags", click the + button, and add '-ObjC'. '-all_load' and '-force_load' are no longer needed.

**Details:**
I found some answers on various forums, blogs and apple docs. Now I try make short summary of my searches and experiments.

Problem was caused by (citation from apple Technical Q&A QA1490 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html):

> Objective-C does not define linker
> symbols for each function (or method,
> in Objective-C) - instead, linker
> symbols are only generated for each
> class. If you extend a pre-existing
> class with categories, the linker does
> not know to associate the object code
> of the core class implementation and
> the category implementation. This
> prevents objects created in the
> resulting application from responding
> to a selector that is defined in the
> category.

And their solution:

> To resolve this issue, the static
> library should pass the -ObjC  option
> to the linker. This flag causes the
> linker to load every object file in
> the library that defines an
> Objective-C class or category. While
> this option will typically result in a
> larger executable (due to additional
> object code loaded into the
> application), it will allow the
> successful creation of effective
> Objective-C static libraries that
> contain categories on existing
> classes.

and there is also recommendation in iPhone Development FAQ:

> How do I link all the Objective-C
> classes in a static library? Set the
> Other Linker Flags build setting to
> -ObjC.

and flags descriptions:

> -**all_load** Loads all members of static archive libraries.
>
> -**ObjC** Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an
> Objective-C class or category.
>
> -**force_load (path_to_archive)** Loads all members of the specified static
> archive library. Note: -all_load
> forces all members of all archives to
> be loaded. This option allows you to
> target a specific archive.

*we can use force_load to reduce app binary size and to avoid conflicts which all_load can cause in some cases.

Yes, it works with *.a files added to the project.
Yet I had troubles with lib project added as direct dependency. But later I found that it was my fault - direct dependency project possibly was not added properly. When I remove it and add again with  steps:

1. Drag&drop lib project file in app project (or add it with Project->Add to project…).
2. Click on arrow at lib project icon - mylib.a file name shown, drag this mylib.a file and drop it into Target -> Link Binary With Library group.
3. Open target info in fist page (General) and add my lib to dependencies list

after that all works OK. "-ObjC" flag was enough in my case.

I also was interested with idea from http://iphonedevelopmentexperiences.blogspot.com/2010/03/categories-in-static-library.html blog. Author say he can use category from lib without setting -all_load or -ObjC flag. He just add to category h/m files empty dummy class interface/implementation to force linker use this file. And yes, this trick do the job.

But author also said he even not instantiated dummy object. Mm…  As I've found we should explicitly call some "real" code from category file. So at least class function should be called.
And we even need not dummy class. Single c function do the same.

So if we write lib files as:

```
// mylib.h
void useMyLib();

@interface NSObject (Logger)
-(void)logSelf;
@end


// mylib.m
void useMyLib(){
    NSLog(@"do nothing, just for make mylib linked");
}


@implementation NSObject (Logger)
-(void)logSelf{
    NSLog(@"self is:%@", [self description]);
}
@end
```

and if we call useMyLib(); anywhere in App project
then in any class we can use logSelf category method;

```
[self logSelf];
```

And more blogs on theme:

http://t-machine.org/index.php/2009/10/13/how-to-make-an-iphone-static-library-part-1/

http://blog.costan.us/2009/12/fat-iphone-static-libraries-device-and.html

Comment: The Apple tech note appears to have since been modified to say "To resolve this issue, the target linking against the static library must pass the -ObjC option to the linker." which is the opposite of what's quoted above. We just confirmed that you have to include when linking the app and not the library itself.

Comment: According to the doc http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html, we should use -all_load or -force_load flag. As mentioned, the linker does have bug in 64bit Mac App and iPhone App. "Important: For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The workaround is to use the -all_load or -force_load flags."

Comment: @Ken Aspelagh: Thanks, I had the same issue.  The -ObjC and -all_load flags need to be added to the *app itself*, not the library.

Comment: Great answer, though newcomers to this question should note it is now out of date. Check out tonklon's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9224606/322748 (all_load/force_load are no longer needed)

Comment: I got stucked on these things for almost half an hour and with a trial and error I just made it out. Any way thanks. This answer worth a +1 and you got that!!!

Comment: I can confirm @JayPeyer 's comment -- this now works for me with just `-ObjC`, using Xcode 4.5.1.

Comment: Would be great if XCode has the -ObjC flag by default in static library projects.

Comment: Cool - you also found out about the symbol reference trick :-) Indeed, if any symbol (C function, global variable or ObjC class) is loaded from an object file within a static library (.a files are just archives of .o object files), all other ObjC symbols like categories are loaded as well. I found out about this some months ago. Using single object prelink converts the whole content of the library to a single .o file, in that case referencing any symbol from the library has the effect of using -ObjC option.

Answer (score 131):

The answer from Vladimir is actually pretty good, however, I'd like to give some more background knowledge here. Maybe one day somebody finds my reply and may find it helpful.

The compiler transforms source files (.c, .cc, .cpp, .m) into object files (.o). There is one object file per source file. Object files contain symbols, code and data. Object files are not directly usable by the operating system.

Now when building a dynamic library (.dylib), a framework, a loadable bundle (.bundle) or an executable binary, these object files are linked together by the linker to produce something the operating system considers "usable", e.g. something it can directly load to a specific memory address.

However when building a static library, all these object files are simply added to a big archive file, hence the extension of static libraries (.a for archive). So an .a file is nothing than an archive of object (.o) files. Think of a TAR archive or a ZIP archive without compression. It's just easier to copy a single .a  file around than a whole bunch of .o files (similar to Java, where you pack .class files into a .jar archive for easy distribution).

When linking a binary to a static library (= archive), the linker will get a table of all symbols in the archive and check which of these symbols are referenced by the binaries. Only the object files containing referenced symbols are actually loaded by the linker and are considered by the linking process. E.g. if your archive has 50 object files, but only 20 contain symbols used by the binary, only those 20 are loaded by the linker, the other 30 are entirely ignored in the linking process.

This works quite well for C and C++ code, as these languages try to do as much as possible at compile time (though C++ also has some runtime-only features). Obj-C, however, is a different kind of language. Obj-C heavily depends on runtime features and many Obj-C features are actually runtime-only features. Obj-C classes actually have symbols comparable to C functions or global C variables (at least in current Obj-C runtime). A linker can see if a class is referenced or not, so it can determine a class being in use or not. If you use a class from an object file in a static library, this object file will be loaded by the linker because the linker sees a symbol being in use. Categories are a runtime-only feature, categories aren't symbols like classes or functions and that also means a linker cannot determine if a category is in use or not.

If the linker loads an object file containing Obj-C code, all Obj-C parts of it are always part of the linking stage. So if an object file containing categories is loaded because any symbol from it is considered "in use" (be it a class, be it a function, be it a global variable), the categories are loaded as well and will be available at runtime. Yet if the object file itself is not loaded, the categories in it will not be available at runtime. An object file containing **only** categories is **never** loaded because it contains **no symbols** the linker would **ever** consider "in use". And this is the whole problem here.

Several solutions have been proposed and now that you know how all this plays together, let's have another look on the proposed solution:

1. One solution is to add `-all_load` to the linker call. Actually it tells the linker the following "*Load all object files of all archives regardless if you see any symbol in use or not*'. Of course, that will work; but it may also produce rather big binaries.
2. Another solution is to add `-force_load` to the linker call including the path to the archive. This flag works exactly like `-all_load`, but only for the specified archive. Of course this will work as well.
3. The most popular solution is to add `-ObjC` to the linker call. This flag tells the linker "*Load all object files from all archives if you see that they contain any Obj-C code*". And "any Obj-C code" includes categories. This will work as well and it will not force loading of object files containing no Obj-C code (these are still only loaded on demand).
4. Another solution is the rather new Xcode build setting `Perform Single-Object Prelink`. If enabled, all the object files (remember, there is one per source file) are merged together into a single object file (that is not real linking, hence the name *PreLink*) and this single object file (sometimes also called a "master object file") is then added to the archive. If now any symbol of the master object file is considered in use, the whole master object file is considered in use and thus all Objective-C parts of it are always loaded. And since classes are normal symbols, it's enough to use a single class from such a static library to also get all the categories.
5. The final solution is the trick Vladimir added at the very end of his answer. Place a "*fake symbol*" into any source file declaring only categories. If you want to use any of the categories at runtime, make sure you somehow reference the *fake symbol* at compile time, as this causes the object file to be loaded by the linker and thus also all Obj-C code in it. E.g. it could be a function with an empty function body (which will do nothing when being called) or it could be a global variable accessed (e.g. a global `int` once read or once written, this is sufficient). Unlike all other solutions above, this solution shifts control about which categories are available at runtime to the compiled code (if it wants them to be linked and available, it accesses the symbol, otherwise it doesn't access the symbol and the linker will ignore it).

That's all folks.

Oh, wait, there's one more thing:
The linker has an option named `-dead_strip`. What does this option do? If the linker decided to load an object file, all symbols of the object file become part of the linked binary, whether they are used or not. E.g. an object file contains 100 functions, but only one of them is used by the binary, all 100 functions are still added to the binary because object files are either added as a whole or they are not added at all. Adding an object file partially is usually not supported by linkers.

However, if you tell the linker to "dead strip", the linker will first add all the object files to the binary, resolve all the references and finally scan the binary for symbols not in use (or only in use by other symbols not in use). All the symbols found to be not in use are then removed as part of the optimization stage. In the example above, the 99 unused functions are removed again. This is very useful if you use options like `-load_all`, `-force_load` or `Perform Single-Object Prelink` because these options can easily blow up binary sizes dramatically in some cases and the dead stripping will remove unused code and data again.

Dead stripping works very well for C code (e.g. unused functions, variables and constants are removed as expected) and it also works quite good for C++ (e.g. unused classes are removed). It is not perfect, in some cases some symbols are not removed even though it would be okay to remove them, but in most cases it works quite well for these languages.

What about Obj-C? Forget about it! There is no dead stripping for Obj-C. As Obj-C is a runtime-feature language, the compiler cannot say at compile time whether a symbol is really in use or not. E.g. an Obj-C class is not in use if there is no code directly referencing it, correct? Wrong! You can dynamically build a string containing a class name, request a class pointer for that name and dynamically allocate the class. E.g. instead of

```
MyCoolClass * mcc = [[MyCoolClass alloc] init];
```

I could also write

```
NSString * cname = @"CoolClass";
NSString * cnameFull = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My%@", cname];
Class mmcClass = NSClassFromString(cnameFull);
id mmc = [[mmcClass alloc] init];
```

In both cases `mmc` is a reference to an object of the class "MyCoolClass", but there is **no direct reference** to this class in the second code sample (not even the class name as a static string). Everything happens only at runtime. And that's even though classes **are** actually real symbols. It's even worse for categories, as they are not even real symbols.

So if you have a static library with hundreds of objects, yet most of your binaries only need a few of them, you may prefer not to use the solutions (1) to (4) above. Otherwise you end up with very big binaries containing all these classes, even though most of them are never used. For classes you usually don't need any special solution at all since classes have real symbols and as long as you reference them directly (not as in the second code sample), the linker will identify their usage pretty well on its own. For categories, though, consider solution (5), as it makes it possible to only include the categories you really need.

E.g. if you want a category for NSData, e.g. adding a compression/decompression method to it, you'd create a header file:

```
// NSData+Compress.h
@interface NSData (Compression)
    - (NSData *)compressedData;
    - (NSData *)decompressedData;
@end

void import_NSData_Compression ( );
```

and an implementation file

```
// NSData+Compress
@implementation NSData (Compression)
    - (NSData *)compressedData 
    {
        // ... magic ...
    }

    - (NSData *)decompressedData
    {
        // ... magic ...
    }
@end

void import_NSData_Compression ( ) { }
```

Now just make sure that anywhere in your code `import_NSData_Compression()` is called. It doesn't matter where it is called or how often it is called. Actually it doesn't really have to be called at all, it's enough if the linker thinks so. E.g. you could put the following code anywhere in your project:

```
__attribute__((used)) static void importCategories ()
{
    import_NSData_Compression();
    // add more import calls here
}
```

You don't have to ever call `importCategories()` in your code, the attribute will make the compiler and linker believe that it is called, even in case it is not.

And a final tip: 
If you add `-whyload` to the final link call, the linker will print in the build log which object file from which library it did load because of which symbol in use. It will only print the first symbol considered in use, but that is not necessarily the only symbol in use of that object file.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `-whyload`, trying to debug why the linker is doing something can be quite difficult!

Comment: There is an option `Dead Code Stripping` in `Build Settings>Linking`. Is it the same as `-dead_strip` added in `Other Linker Flags`?

Comment: @Sean Yes, it is the same. Just read the "Quick Help" that exists for every build setting, the answer is right there: http://postimg.org/image/n7megftnr/full/

Comment: @Mecki Thanks. I tried to get rid of `-ObjC`, so I tried your hack but it complains `"import_NSString_jsonObject()", referenced from:
importCategories() in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found`. I put `import_NSString_jsonObject` in my embedded Framework named `Utility`, and add `#import <Utility/Utility.h>` with `__attribute__` statement at the end of my `AppDelegate.h`.

Comment: @Sean If the linker cannot find the symbol, you are not linking against the static library that contains the symbol. Just importing a h file from a framework will not make Xcode link against the framework. The framework must be explicitly linked to in the link with frameworks build phase. You may want to open up an own question for your linking issue, answering in comments is cumbersome and you also cannot provide information like build log output.

Comment: @Mecki Thanks for your reply. Actually I already put `Utility.framework` in `Link Binary with Libraries` under `Build Phases`. I will study and let you know.

Comment: @Sean if it is a Framework - most likely it is not a static lib, but rather a dynamic lib and your issue is not related to this question

Comment: @MottiShneor Theoretically a framework can be static. This is not commonly used but a nice way to combine a static library with its headers. Static frameworks work just like dynamic ones, except that you don't need to embed them after linking. Yet if symbols are missing on linking stage, this usually has one of two causes: They got stripped or their visibility attribute is wrong (they were not exported to the symbol table). First case cannot happen with static libraries, as those are never stripped.

Comment: @Mecki Oh, of course... there were times static-lib-based Frameworks were all that existed on iOS, I just thought to help in case his was a dynamic (normal as of today) framework. I struggled a lot with static-libs on iOS back in the iOS 4,5,6 and 7 times... I even created Xcode templates for them to make creating them easier.

Answer (score 24):

This issue has been [fixed in LLVM](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7431). The fix ships as part of LLVM 2.9 The first Xcode version to contain the fix is Xcode 4.2 shipping with LLVM 3.0. **The usage of `-all_load` or `-force_load` is no longer needed when working with XCode 4.2** `-ObjC` is still needed.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm working on an iOS project using Xcode 4.3.2, compiling with LLVM 3.1 and this was still an issue for me.

Comment: Ok, that was a little imprecise. The `-ObjC` flag is still needed and will always be. The workaround was the usage of `-all_load` or `-force_load`. And that is not needed anymore. I fixed my answer above.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to including the -all_load flag (even if it's unnecessary)? Does it affect compile / launch time in any way?

Comment: I'm working with Xcode Version 4.5 (4G182) and the -ObjC flag moves my unrecognised selector error from the 3rd party dependency I'm trying to use into what looks like the the depths of the Objective C runtime: "-[__NSArrayM map:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...". Any clues?

Answer (score 19):

Here's what you need to do to resolve this problem completely when compiling your static library:

Either go to Xcode Build Settings and set Perform Single-Object Prelink to YES or 
`GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE = YES` in your build configuration file.

By default,the linker generates an .o file for each .m file. So categories gets different .o files. When the linker looks at a static library .o files, it doesn't create an index of all symbols per class (Runtime will, doesn't matter what).

This directive will ask the linker to pack all objects together into one big .o file and by this it forces the linker that process the static library to get index all class categories.

Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: This fixed it for me without having to add -ObjC to the linking target.

Comment: After updating to the latest version of [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit) library, I had to use this setting to fix the issue (I was already using -ObjC flag but still seeing the issue).

Comment: Actually your answer is not quite right. I does not "ask the linker to pack all categories of the same class together into one .o file", it ask the linker to link all object files (.o) into a single, big object file before creating a static library out of them/it. Once any symbol is referenced from the library, all the symbols are loaded. However, this will not work if no symbol is referenced (e.g. if it will not work if there are only categories in the library).

Comment: I don't think that this will work if you add categories to existing classes, such as NSData.

Comment: I too am having trouble adding categories to existing classes. My plugin can’t recognize them at run time.

Answer (score 9):

One factor that is rarely mentioned whenever the static library linking discussion comes up is the fact that you **must also include the categories themselves in the build phases->copy files and compile sources of the static library itself**.

Apple also doesn't emphasize this fact in their recently published [Using Static Libraries in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/iOSStaticLibraries.pdf) either.

I spent a whole day trying all sorts of variations of -objC and -all_load etc.. but nothing came out of it.. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932856/calling-method-on-category-included-from-iphone-static-library-causes-nsinvalida) question brought that issue to my attention. (don't get me wrong.. you still have to do the -objC stuff.. but it's more than just that).

also another action that has always helped me is that I always build the included static library first on its own.. then i build the enclosing application..

Answer (score -1):

You probably  need to have the category in you're static library's "public" header: #import "MyStaticLib.h"