# Encode UIImage to base64 string on iOS

Tags: ios, encoding, uiimage, base64, encode

I have a problem with encoding UIImage to the base64 string using [this category](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html).

This is the code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"], 1.0);
NSString *imageString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
```

I get this error:

> -[NSConcreteData base64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x906800
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData
>   base64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x906800'

I just cannot figure it out where the problem is? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just figured it out. Xcode did not put .m file into Compile Sources und project Build Phases. Why is this happening all the time on Xcode 4.3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998483/objective-c-category-causing-unrecognized-selector ?

Comment: Just double-checking, you have #imported the category into the class you are coding?

Comment: Check out this link, you'll find a pretty detailed explanation on this. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: It works. Do you know how to remove newlines in outputted string ?

Comment: I asked the same thing about xcode 4.3.  I realized that when adding single files or classes to a project the target checkbox is often empty when you are choosing how to add it.  Be sure it is ticked, or you sure will be heh.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Checkbox is not checked always and I did not pay attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode did not put .m file into Compile Sources under project Build Phases. This happened cos I was not careful choosing the right target (project/test).