# Objective-C Categories not being recognized?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unrecognized-selector, objective-c-category

Well, this is quite a weird issue. (I just hope it has something to do with my not-playing-that-much-with-Cocoa-for-a-while, or else...)

So, the issue is quite straightforward :

- I'm using **Xcode 4.3.3** (a very simple test project - **10.7 SDK** - **no ARC**)
- I'm creating a **Category** on some Class *(e.g. `NSProgressIndicator`)*
- I'm including the appropriate header file
- When trying to use any of my Category's methods (however, it still shows up in the dropdown of available commands), I'm getting an error :

> [NSProgressIndicator start]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f9f4b91a0a0

#### The code

(as an example - it has happened with other (100-times tested) categories):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSProgressIndicator (NSProgressIndicator_Functions)

- (void)start;
- (void)stop;

@end
```

---

```
#import "NSProgressIndicator+Functions.h"


@implementation NSProgressIndicator (NSProgressIndicator_Functions)

- (void)start
{
    [self setHidden:NO];
    [self startAnimation:nil];
}

- (void)stop
{
    [self setHidden:YES];
    [self stopAnimation:nil];
}

@end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the category's implementation (.m) file included in your target's Compile Sources build phase? That'd be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen UPDATE: Nope, actually it wasn't! OMG, I feel like stupid. Andrew, please post that as a proper answer (so that others take notice too), and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the same issue as:

[Objective-C Category Causing unrecognized selector][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998483/objective-c-category-causing-unrecognized-selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand my comment into a real answer:

Make sure the category's implementation (.m) file is included in your target's Compile Sources build phase. Importing the header is enough to tell the compiler that there is a category on NSProgressIndicator which adds a `-start` method. Unless the category's implementation is actually compiled and linked into the finished binary (or the method implementation is added at runtime, etc), NSProgressIndicator won't actually respond to the `start` message at runtime. Because of Objective-C's dynamic message send behavior, there's no way the compiler can tell at compile time whether or not NSProgressIndicator is *actually* going to respond to that message, which is why you don't get a warning or an error.