# Linker cannot find a class that should be there

Tags: objective-c, linker, categories, core-telephony, class-extensions

I have a project that uses the Core Telephony framework. Recently my code stopped working on a `CTCarrier` category, the linker complains that it can’t find the `CTCarrier` class:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTCarrier", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CTCarrier_$_Foo in CTTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

This is a sample code that triggers the error above:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

@interface CTCarrier (Foo)
- (void) doFoo;
@end

@implementation CTCarrier (Foo)
- (void) doFoo {}
@end
```

If I change the category to class extension, the code suddenly builds:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

@interface CTCarrier ()
- (void) doFoo;
@end

@implementation CTCarrier
- (void) doFoo {}
@end
```

What’s going on? Sample code [on GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/Xcode-Linker-Issue).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in 4.2 that doesn't allow the direct creation of a CTCarrier object, the proper way to access CTCarrier is via the CTTelephonyNetworkInfo object like so:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephony = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = telephony.subscriberCellularProvider;
[telephony release];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you don't really are implementing CTCarrier class but only add a method to it. The categories provide a way to add methods to an already defined implementation.

Comment: I know how categories work, at least I hope so :) The problem is that the linker complains that it cannot find a class that I am adding a category to. When I switch to a class extension instead of the category, the linker stops complaining. That’s weird.

Comment: The class is implemented in other .m file? I'm referring to '@implementation CTCarrier'

Comment: The `CTCarrier` class comes from the Core Telephony framework.

Comment: Interesting... Can you paste in your question the gcc line that's compile your category file?

Comment: I’ve uploaded a sample project to [GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/Xcode-Linker-Issue).

Comment: Maybe here are a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library