# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when calling category method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a static library that i made for encryption an XML serialization with i use in my projects. 
This code worked perfectly until now. but when i included it in my latest project i got an error, i know this error usually appears when the object i call is not properly allocated witch is not the case here  the NSLog returns the NSData for my encryption.

What could be the problem?

The error i get is

> -[NSConcreteData base64EncodingWithLineLength:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x1c9150
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData
>   base64EncodingWithLineLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1c9150'

Here is my code:

```
NSData * encryptedMsg =[crypto encrypt:MsgEnc key:[accessdata->Certificate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];
        NSLog(@"encryptedMsg %@",encryptedMsg);
        NSString * msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [encryptedMsg base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, `base64EncodingWithLineLength` is a method that is not defined in `NSData` but in a category called `NSData+Base64.h`. The reason why you get the error is that you did not add that category to your project, so that the method is called, it is not found.

So you should add "NSData+Base64.*" files to your project. Get them from [here](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine).

EDIT:

Since the OP mention that the category is included in a static library and assuming the static library is correctly linked, then a possible fix for this issue is adding the

```
-ObjC
```

flag to the "Other linker flags" in your Build Settings. This flag will force the loading of all symbols in Objective C categories, preventing them from being optimized out through the linker.

Comment: i already did, i checked that twice  Could it be some setting problems for the projects? I recently switched to xCode 4.0.2

Comment: Right-click on NSData+Base64.m, get Information for that file and ensure it is added to the target you are compiling...

Comment: It's included , i don't know what was wrong but it works now, I made a clean, deleted the app of the iphone, and it worked when i rebuild the app, some freak bug i guess. Tanks for the help. In a normal situation of "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" your solution would be the fix for this sow i will mark it as right answer, cheers

Comment: Same here; it's included. This is happening in the Soomla iOSStore project. They call it and they have it included in their project, which I have a reference to in mine.

Comment: @Almo: if you are using a static lib including the NSData extension, make sure it is compiled with the -ObjC and -load_all linker flags.

Comment: @sergio hey thanks for the tip! It led me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library

-all_load is no longer needed. Putting -ObjC into the linker options for the main project (not the referenced static lib) fixed the problem. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid `base64EncodingWithLineLength:` is a Category method attached onto `NSData`. That means you should compile/link against the code that implements `base64EncodingWithLineLength` for `NSData` category.

Answer (score 0):

It can help if category refers to Core Data entity:
   set class for the entity in the managed object model.