# xcode 4 static library link on multiple project inside same workspace for iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode4, static-libraries, workspace

As mentioned in title I need some help on working workspace with static libraries!
This is my situation:

1. App project;
2. Library A
3. Library B

The depends:

- App projects depends by Library A and Library B
- Library A depends by Library B
- Library B is atomic

So ... I have tried a lot of configurations, linking B to A, and A to App; or linking B to A and A & B to App ... but always have error from linker. In first case linker cannot find symbols of library B, in second case linker return error of symbol duplicate in A and B!

Someone can help me please???

Answer (score 2):

Static libraries can't link with each other. If Library A depends on Library B, all you need to do is to link your App to both libraries A and B.

If you still get a linker error, my guess is that one of the libraries adds an Objective-C category and you've run into the well-known issue that needs to be resolved with -force_load. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library/2615407#2615407)