# Xcode extensions class call method: sigabrt

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, sigabrt

I have a strange problem ...
I have two projects in Xcode: PR1 and PR2. PR2 is linked in PR1.
In the PR2 i have class and some "extensions class". In PR1 i use some extensions methods.
I have no compilation errors but when I call these methods have a sigabrt ... I do not find these methods! And 'I do not understand the strange and
reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PR2 creates static libraries you may be interested in looking at [this detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library). The short answer is try the following compilation flags:

> **-all_load** Loads all members of static archive libraries.
>
> **-ObjC** Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an Objective-C class or category.
>
> **-force_load** (path_to_archive) Loads all members of the specified static archive library. Note: -all_load forces all members of all
>   archives to be loaded. This option allows you to target a specific
>   archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable `NSZombiesEnabled`.

In Xcode 4.x: Press ⌥⌘R; From the tab "Info | Arguments | Diagnostics" select Diagnostics and click "Enable Zombie Objects"

Also, please post more codes related to SIGABRT.