# About Other linker flag“-ObjC”?

Tags: objective-c

Description:
1. In my project(A)，I define CountryInfo class in "CountryInfoLoader.h";

```
@interface CountryInfo : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * code;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * name;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * prefix;

@end

@interface CountryInfoLoader : NSObject

+ (CountryInfo*)currentCountry;
+ (NSArray*)loadAllCountries;
+ (NSDictionary*)loadGroupCountries;

@end
```

2. In my static library project(B, like "libB.a"), there is the same "CountryInfo.h" and  "CountryInfo.m";
3. "A" dependence on "B"；
4. Some modules in “A” import "CountryInfoLoader.h" to get CountryInfo, xcode don‘t show duplicate symbol error;
5. when I add Other linker flag“-ObjC“ to fix some category error, there is  duplicate symbol error on "CountryInfo"。

So：
 Why adding linker flag“-ObjC” causes the above error?

Comment: 3. Why do you have the same class in multiple libraries?

Comment: A and B  are maintained by two teams.

Comment: One of the teams will have to let go.

Comment: Yeah agree with @Droppy Refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517427/while-using-two-static-library-in-project-conflict-due-to-class-with-same-name

Comment: Read the manpage "Loads all members of static archive libraries that define an Objective C class or a category".