# How to describe the inner class in oc?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I define CountryInfo class in "CountryInfoLoader.h";

```
@interface CountryInfo : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * code;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * name;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * prefix;

@end

@interface CountryInfoLoader : NSObject

+ (CountryInfo*)currentCountry;
+ (NSArray*)loadAllCountries;
+ (NSDictionary*)loadGroupCountries;

@end
```

So: 1. How could I describe "CountryInfo" defining in "CountryInfoLoader.h"?  innner class(like java), instance-method, property, or what?

2. what is the difference betwwen the defination in "CountryInfoLoader.h" and extracting to "CountryInfo.h"/"CountryInfo.m"?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have namespaces, and it doesn't have inner classes.  The closest you can get is to define the class entirely in the implementation file (`.m`).  If you need to refer to it in the `@interface`, use `@class`.

Comment: what is the difference betwwen the defination in "CountryInfoLoader.h" and extracting to "CountryInfo.h" / "CountryInfo.m"?

Comment: Visibility to the compiler.  Symbols defined in a single compilation unit (a single file: e.g. .m, .c, .cpp, etc.) are not visible to other compilation units.  This gives some semblance of privacy.  Objective-C is very dynamic, though, so at runtime there's virtually no privacy at all.

Comment: I think the OP is attempting to "hide this class away" in order to avoid linker errors.  See [his other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805510/about-other-linker-flag-objc).  It won't end well.

Comment: But i define it  in “"CountryInfoLoader.h"”,  is it invisiable also?