# Objective-C category is not loaded - How to debug this

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, restkit, objective-c-category

I have two projects which the [RestKit framework](http://restkit.org).

One project works without problems but another project fails, as soon as the RestKit framework is used.

I found out that the failing code is this:

```
return [anNSString MD5];
```

The `MD5` method is a category method and is imported like this:

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"
```

However, in one project, I keep getting the following error:

```
-[__NSCFString MD5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88a3390
```

I understand the basics of categories, and that they can be loaded at runtime, but I don't see why the category does not get loaded in this case.

These are the files on github: [NSString+MD5.m](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Network/NSString+MD5.m), [NSString+MD5.h](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Network/NSString+MD5.h),

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you have the -ObjC flag enabled. Or it will not link categories in a static library.

[Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library)

Answer (score 7):

It's not enough to just include the header file.  You also need to compile and link the `.m` file in your project.

Comment: I am implicitly compiling the sources by adding the individual products as dependencies.