# Objective C Category not loaded when added as a dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category

I have a project which has a category for NSString as below

```
@interface NSString (DataEncoding)

- (NSString *)com_EncryptWithISBN;

@end

@implementation NSString (DataEncoding)

- (NSString *)com_EncryptWithISBN
{
    return [self com_EncryptWithKey:[HMHBundleInfoAccess sharedInstance].ISBN];
}
@end
```

I have this in a different project(B) and it works fine within that project. Now I moved project B to another project A. Now the same code is giving me an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   com_EncryptWithISBN]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xd334600'

I doubt whether the category is not linked properly when added as a subproject of Project A.

I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714746/objective-c-category-is-not-loaded-how-to-debug-this) but no change. Do I need to add project B as a target dependency for Project A?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just copy the code for the category to project a. if you are using cocoa pods, you can create a git repo for all the categories, and add the git repo to your cocoapods. That is a lot of work for just two projects.

Answer (score 0):

Add header NSString+DataEncoding.h (header of your category) to the files where you are using encrypting (where you are performing this selector).

Comment: This is just wrong. If there wasn't a header it wouldn't compile. But he's getting an exception so it's a runtime error.

Comment: Not necessary. It's possible that calls were executed through performSelector:.

Comment: If you use `-[performSelecor:]` you should also enable `-Wstrict-selector-match`! ;) See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/124574) for more details. And then it would be a compile time error ;)

Comment: I didn't know about this. If this flag is enabled my answer is useless. Agree with you.