# Linker error when trying to use SmartfoxServer-framework with a Kobold-2D project

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

When trying to use the SmartfoxServer-framework inside a Kobold2d project we are getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCAsyncObject", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCTextureCache+CCBigImageExtensions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

This happends due to the fact, that we have to include the `-ObjC` linker flag to have the categories loaded, which are defined in the SmartfoxServer-framework. I already read about the need to force-link a static library which contains categories [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163759/why-cctexturecacheccbigimageextensions-isnt-linked-in-my-kobold2d-project), but the SmartFoxServer-Framework isn't a static library.

Is there a way to force load a framework, so it includes all the categories without using the `-ObjC` linker flag? Or is there a convenient way to convert a framework to a static library? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you made sure that it's been added to the Target. You can do this by clicking on the file, and using the right panel (inspector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using CCBigImage, you can deselect the CCTextureCache+CCBigImageExtensions.h and .m files from the target.

Open the Kobold2D-Libraries project and browse to the group /Extensions/CCBigImage. From the menu choose View -> Utilities -> File Inspector. Select each file and uncheck the target checkbox in File Inspector. Now this particular class won't be compiled anymore and the error is gone.

The problem seems to be that this category uses a private class that's defined only in the implementation file. Unfortunately force loading the entire cocos2d-iphone-extensions project is not a solution because this brings up other errors.