# add categories in xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I copied the timeAgo category for NSDate in XCODE4, but i get the following runtime error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate timeAgo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e000'

I read in other posts i need to add a linking flag, which I did as follows:

[image]

But its still not working.  What am I missing to use third party categories?

Comment: Are you `#import`'ing your category?  If so, I know at least the DP1 of Xcode was having some troubles with categories.

Comment: yeah did...everything builds fine.  am i putting in the flags correctly? thx

Comment: Yes, the flag is correct.  Is this inside a static library?  If so, you could `all_load` or `force_load`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C categories in static library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library)

Comment: You need to use the `-all_load` flag for now.  See the link in my prior comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you ought to mess with the linkers, at least not there. Wherever you got that category from may have mentioned that the file you put that in needs to be compiled, which you check by going to your project settings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. Make sure the category's .m file is in there.

Comment: i don't remember having to do this in xcode3.2.6.  so whenever i copy over a .m from another project, i need to manually add it into compile sources? thx

Comment: You get the option when you add files to your project. Make sure you always opt for "Add to target <xxx>", that will automatically do it for you. This checkbox isn't always checked (not sure what that depends on), so check that when you add a file.