# Crash when tapping cell in GMGridView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gmgridview

i'm trying to use the `GMGridView` library, everything works but when i tap in a cell the app crash in a method of the library with this error: `[UILongPressGestureRecognizer hasRecognizedValidGesture]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance...
I've tried to add "-ObjC -all_load" tho Other Linker Flags section but this give me an error with another library (`MWPhotoBrowser`).
There is someone who have resolved this?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the linker flags:

```
-ObjC -all_load
```

([source](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/issues/88)).

If you are using Xcode 4.2 and LLVM 3.0, only `-ObjC` is needed.

For an explanation of why this is necessary, have a look at [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library).

[Look here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html) for steps to set linker flags in Xcode 3. In Xcode 4, you have to select your targets, and then the Build Settings tab in the right pane.

Comment: I've tried but when i add -ObjC -all_load i've another error i think because there is another library linked. Xcode error is "duplicate symbol"

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4, i've tried also with -ObjC only but i have the same error. I've added the library in the targets

Comment: please note: Xcode 4.2 and LLVM 3.0 (Xcode 4.2 supports more compilers, so you could be using a different one). which duplicate symbol do you get?

Comment: I've resolved, i've added -ObjC in Other Linker Flags and then i've removed the link of the other library (that give me the duplicate) from "Copy bundle resources" in build phases.