# ios [__NSCFString MD5String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have the following problem that I do not succeed to solve. Your help will be appreciated.

To calculate a md5 from a NSS
tring, a category has been defined by :

### NSString-md5.h

```
@interface NSString (MD5)
- (NSString *)MD5String;
@end
```

### NSString-md5.m

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import "NSString-md5.h"
@implementation NSString(MD5)
- (NSString *)MD5String
    {is
    const char *cstr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];    
    CC_MD5( cstr, strlen(cstr), result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];  
    }
@end
```

### calling code (extract)

```
#import "NSString-md5.h"
...
NSLog(@"1 %@ ",message.text);
[message.text MD5String];
```

aborts with error message :

```
2013-03-03 19:06:14.104 coffreFort[1230:11303] 1 aze 
2013-03-03 19:06:22.777 coffreFort[1230:11303] -[__NSCFString MD5String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71e62b0
2013-03-03 19:06:22.777 coffreFort[1230:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString MD5String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71e62b0'
```

message.text is an IBOutlet defined by

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *message;
```

Comment: Have you compiled/linked the category along with the other source files? It seems that the category is not loaded.

Comment: Convention for category is **+** but he is using **-** !!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That should not be a problem...

Comment: That is convention Not rule :)   2nd point: what is  `{is` in implementation?

Comment: is the category part of the current target?

Comment: There is no convention saying that category methods should be class methods and not instance methods, that's nonsense.

Answer (score 10):

It's an issue with CLANG (which they promised would be fixed) where categories often go unloaded, especially in the context of frameworks or libraries..  You have to pass in the linker flags `-all_load` (or `-force_load`) in addition to `-ObjC` to force the linker to include them with your binary.

Comment: Only adding `-ObjC` in the Other Linker Flags resolved my same issue.

Comment: This is not an issue with clang as you get exactly the same result with gcc. This is an issue with how Obj-C works and what categories actually are under the hood. Categories are not symbols in the classical C sense and are added dynamically at run time, hence a compiler cannot know if they are referenced at link time. For a more detailed explanation, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264650/15809