# Available linker flags and it's use in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, linker-flags

I'm little bit confused with the linker flags available on iOS.

This question may not be a good one accoring to the faq, but I don't know anything about the linker flags, and I'm curious about it. That's why I'm asking it here.

1. What is the use of -`ObjC` linker flag ?
2. What is the use of `-all_load` ?
3. What is the use of `-force_load` ?

What are the other frequently used linker flags available for iOS ?

Please help me to understand the linker flag usage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2615407/642626

Comment: @Midhun MP please do not forget to mark answer as accepted if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `-ObjC`
  flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.
- `-all_load`
  flag forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code.
- `-force_load`
  option must be followed by a path to an archive, and every object file in that archive will be loaded.

for additional information you can read this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html)

**EDIT**

you can see all flags supported by ld in ld ManPage in following [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html)