# How to stop building supporting files (like MagicalRecord) every time I do a build

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I have some support files, such as MagicalRecord and others that get compiled each and every time.  Is there a way to prevent this unless I specifically want them recompiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea would be to move all your support files from your application project to a static library project.

Then, you would build the library "once" and link with your application afterwards.

Apple describes that process [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html).

You have to be pretty careful to build your library in all required architectures, 
and maybe you have to add -ObjC as a linker flag.

A good starting point is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library).

Comment: Thank you so much... I knew there was a way to do it!  :D