# Unrecognized Selector Sent to To instance for UIButton+AFNetworking.h (UIImageView+AFNetworking too)

Tags: ios, uibutton, afnetworking

i am trying to integrate the AFNetworking class for UIButton (i am calling a profile page and am loading in the avatar for the user async'd).

https://gist.github.com/dpettigrew/2925847

> Xcode error: -[UIRoundedRectButton setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd2431a0

I tried to follow this example (https://github.com/luisespinoza/ActivityIndicatorImageURL) and i'm getting the same error on the UIImageView too.

I verified that all the files are copied into xcode and including in the build phases area. The thing that doesn't make sense though, is when i hold command and click the method, where i'm calling it, it jumps to the right method no problem. Any ideas? how do i get xcode to find the method on run time?

`self->avatar` is the UIButton linked via an IBOutlet in my storyboard.

```
UIImage *imageTemp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_avatar.png"];
[self->avatar setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:imageTemp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

#### Edit

Also note that i do have the following in my .h

```
#import "UIButton+AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

Comment: Sorry, i cannot figure out any other suggestions to fix your issue. Weird. :S

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My previous answer is totally wrong, because subclass inherit methods of the superclass. I answered like it were a class cluster.

Are you using AFNetworking as a static library? If so, you have to add the -ObjC linker flag.

Look the accepter solution here:([Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library))

Comment: ya, still same problem. :( i recorded a short short video to show you what i'm seeing. http://screencast.com/t/yrhePjgpT

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is but here is a sample project that uses both the UIButton and the UIImageView categories

http://numberpress.co/personal/UIButtonAFNetworkingTest.zip

Comment: thanks david, i'll take a look. i looked at the UIImageView+AFNetworking example and didn't see anything there either.

Answer (score 0):

if you come across this and can't ifgure it out, i recommend trying UIButton+WebCache.h

unfortunately i had issues with this too (the cache was far too strict, only looking at the URL and payload size, which were always the same so it never got reset, so i just don't use the cache part)