# No visible @interface in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, static-linking, podspec

I am trying to modulize my app by splitting it in different sub projects.
Inspired by [this idea](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/architecting-a-large-ios-app-with-cocoapods). So I splited my project to static libraries followed by [that tutorial](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/developing-static-library-for-ios-with-cocoapods/). I created a first library with some costume `UIHelpers/Views`. It has some dependencies which I defined in `PodSpec` file followed by [AFNetworking example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec). (one of the dependencies is [Choosy](https://github.com/substantial/choosy)). I stored this library in bitBucket. Everything is working fine for that library(I can build it in Xcode). The problem start when I create a `Model` Library. I specify  Git path of `UIHelpers` in the `Model PodFile`. Every time I get an error of `No visible @interface` for a category in `Choosy` (the error come from CocoaPod NOT in my project, the category is imported in the `.m`file). I tried to play with `link flags` `-ObjC,$(inhereted),-force_load` included all of them.[Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library/2615407#2615407) I cleaned the derived data.
I read the [CocoaPodTroubleShoutes](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html).

Can somebody suggest what can be tried. There is a lot of question in stuck regarding that compile error but none of them helped me.
I believe the problem somewhere in my `PodSpec`(cant be sure) `pod lib linit` I receive :
`- ERROR | [iOS]  Choosy/Choosy/Model/ChoosyAppInfo.m:32:19: error: no visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'applyMaskImage:completion:'`
My PodSec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    #I tried this options:
    #s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => $(inherited) }
    #s.compiler_flags = '-ObjC'
    #'-all_load'
    #$(inherited)
    #'-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0', '-Wno-format'
    #'-force_load'

   s.prefix_header_contents = '#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>', '#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>','#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>','#import "ARNStyles.h"'
   s.description  = <<-DESC
               A longer description of ARNUIHelpers in Markdown format.
               DESC
   s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/ARNUIHelpers"
   s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
   s.ios.deployment_target = "7.0"
   s.source_files  = 'UIHelpers/**/*.{h,m}' 
   s.requires_arc = true

   s.subspec 'Choosy' do |ss|
         ss.requires_arc = true
         ss.compiler_flags = '-force_load'
         ss.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
         ss.dependency 'Choosy'
       # ss.xcconfig = { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" =>      "$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers/Public/Choosy"}
        # ss.ios.public_header_files = 'UIImage+ImageEffects.h'
   end

   s.subspec 'Dependencies' do |ss|
        #ss.ios.public_header_files = 'UIImage+ImageEffects.h'
         ss.requires_arc = true 
         ss.dependency 'FormatterKit'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was my fault. The previous developer copied those files from `Choosy` pod and included it manually.We still use `Choosy` in other places. Unfortunately the error wasn't clear enough to deduce what was wrong.