# unrecognized selector "fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler:" in GG Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I try to implement cloud messaging, and I'm facing with a problem, It makes my game terminate. But I don't have this problem with example project.

The relating class's GGLInstanceIDTokenManager, It's a private class in libGGLInstanceIDLib.a lib. The below is what I see on xCode log:

```
2015-06-16 18:13:04.446 BreezeGame[2307:427893] -[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14681290
2015-06-16 18:13:04.713 BreezeGame[2307:427893] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14681290'
```

Why didn't Xcode find fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler: function ?

Please help me to fix it. I'm newbie with Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Do you use `CocoaPods` in your project? If not, you can follow the steps in [this page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client). Also make sure you add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project.

Comment: yes, I followed step by step in the guide. And sure I added GoogleService-Info.plist. I also created a new project, and It worked. So I still don't know why didn't Xcode find that function ? Do you know what some things are that cause problem ?

Comment: I think you were missing the -ObjC linker flag in your project file settings. Since the method is defined in a catgory and if you don't have the setting the linker is not going to add these category methods and it's going to fail. 

Here is more info on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `nm` on the library and apparently there is an Internal category on `GGLInstanceIDTokenManager` which does declare this function,

> libGGLInstanceIDLib.a(GGLInstanceIDTokenManager+Internal.o): 00001230
>   t -[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager(Internal)
>   deleteRegisteredTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:handler:]
>   000029cc s -[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager(Internal)
>   deleteRegisteredTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:handler:].eh
>   00000230 t -[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager(Internal)
>   fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler:]
>   00002894 s -[GGLInstanceIDTokenManager(Internal)
>   fetchTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:keyPair:options:handler:].eh

Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Maybe you should file a bug on [gcm's github tracker](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the bundle id of my app was not the same as the one in GoogleService-Info.plist