# Swizzling Not Working in a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

I'm developing an iOS framework and need to write a swizzling method (for viewDidAppear method in UIViewController).

My swizzling method works perfectly in my application. But when I cut/paste my header+implementation files to my framework and launch the app, it doesn't work. I put an `NSLog` inside the `load` method but it doesn't print anything.

For swizzling, I followed this tutorial:
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/30/method-swizzling-objective-c/
I added my "UIViewController+Logging.h" inside the public headers.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your category is not loaded automatically when the app starts. See this question : [Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library)