# check if *.m add to the Target Membership in shell

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

Even if we don't add *.m file to the target Membership, we can also through the script to compile a static library, but run a project use the .a ,it will be crash.Can xcodebuild give me a warning about *.m forget to add the target menbership instead of giving me a wrong *.a.

Comment: Here's a good read for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264650/792677