# Can I add a category method to a Foundation class in a plugin

Tags: objective-c

I have been working on an app, and wrote a lot of category methods on classes like NSNumber.

I now want to turn this into a Unity plugin. The code is now failing in this context, with `-[__NSCFNumber int32Value]: unrecognized selector`.

I have tried the  `-ObjC` flag (OTHER_LDFLAGS) but that doesn’t seem to matter (I can’t add it when building the game engine).

I’ve looked at [Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library) but don’t see anything that addresses this from the context of code in a plugin calling category methods it defines. Am I missing something?

Comment: This must be a linking problem, it's hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: What else do you need to know? The plugin runs fine until it gets to a self-defined category method. I do link with the flag that is supposed to deal with this, but I can’t tell if this has to be used on the host application or the plugin itself.

Comment: Are other methods from the static lib called correctly? Or does it affect only the categories?

Comment: Yes, it gets pretty deep into the code before it hits a category.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had seen a comment elsewhere on StackOverflow that you could not. But the real problem was that I had a build error, and the category in question was not in fact linked.