# How do I get xcode to find the Core Plot header? (iPhone)

Tags: core-plot

I can't seem to make Xcode find the Core Plot header. I've done the following:

1. Clone the hg repo;
2. Drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file into my project;
3. Opened the CP project and compiled it successfully;
4. Dragged the lib file into the target's static link list;
5. Added CorePlot-CocoaTouch as a direct dependency for the target.

But I'm still getting the "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory" error on compile. I've been googling around trying to find an answer, but only seem to find a few people having the same problem but no clear solution. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers I needed are shown on [this blog post](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application), although I found I could use a relative location for the header search path rather than an absolute one. Also don't forget to add `-ObjC` to the linker flags, as well as `-all_load` until the bug has been fixed (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-does/2906210#2906210)).

Answer (score 2):

I found what I was looking for about the same time, even though I'm coding for Mac. The solution assumes the core-plot directory is where your Xcode project is. In my app's target settings, I set this for framework (not header) search path:

```
"${PROJECT_DIR}/core-plot/build/${BUILD_STYLE}/${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}"
```

Quotation marks important. And that was all I needed to do!

Comment: Yes, I learned the hard way about the quotation marks! Although any readers need to make sure *not* to add the framework when building for iOS, it wrecks up the joint ;-)