# Frustrating iPhone Build Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, cocos2d-iphone

I've been fighting this for a few hours now and I'm getting fed up.  My project builds fine with a debug simulator build , release simulator build and a debug device build, but for some reason it won't build with a release device build.  I have a static library containing my cocos2d code, and another static library containing a game engine I wrote.

Because the game engine contains categories, I had to use the all_load linker flag to get it to run.  Without this flag, the code builds fine.  However, I get an unrecognized selector sent to instance exception when I try to run the game.

Here's the first build error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FontLabel in /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o) and /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o)

Ld build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Shapeless normal armv6
cd /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk -L/Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Shapeless.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libChipmunk.a /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/BlackHawk/build/Release-iphoneos/libBlackHawk.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -lz -framework iAd -o /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Shapeless

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FontLabel in /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o) and /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

And here's the second:

```
Ld build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Shapeless normal armv7
cd /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk -L/Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Shapeless.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libChipmunk.a /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/BlackHawk/build/Release-iphoneos/libBlackHawk.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -lz -framework iAd -o /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Apps/Shapeless/build/Shapeless.build/Release-iphoneos/Shapeless.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Shapeless

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FontLabel in /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o) and /Users/helixed/Dropbox/Documents/Development/iPhone/Cocos2d/build/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(FontLabel.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

This is the only think keeping me from releasing, so I really appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Well I've given up on trying to get this to work.  Right now my only solution is to just share code directories.

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar problem, I had accidentally included (#import) the implementation file instead of the header file

When the compiler throws an error that 2 object files contain a duplicate symbol, check for how you have included (#import) the that duplicate symbol's class in the 2 implementation files.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with adding both Facebook sdk and Dropbox sdk. The problem was both of the SDks are using having JSON lib so I removed one of them ans it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have it twice in your project structure?  Check the left side of XCode and look through all the folders and make sure you don't have it in there multiple times.

Comment: Another thing to check is to make sure your Targets are correct.  Check the build target and make sure all the proper libraries are there.

Comment: If it were included twice or the libraries wern't there, wouldn't the build fail with one of the other configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a different set of device architectures (armv6, armv7, etc.) in your Release build than in your Debug build settings (either project, or target which overrides project settings)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the problem.  Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem lies in the unrecognized selector issue that you tried to solve using the -all_load flag. I use cocos2d-iphone in a static library and didn't need that flag. If you read up what it does, it should tell you that it's unlikely to be related to your problem:

[What does the -all_load linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-does)

It fixes linking to static libraries containing ONLY categories and NO classes. That certainly isn't true for cocos2d-iphone.

I recommend to figure out why you get unrecognized selector warnings without this flag. If necessary ask another question here.

You should also turn on the "Unrecognized Selector" build warning in the project's Build Settings, so that you get this warning while compiling as opposed to when it crashes while running the game (then it's too late and you wasted a lot of time). It's one of the settings I *always* turn on in an Xcode project.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I read that post but I interpreted it as containing any categories.  However, the problem I'm trying to solve with the categories is located in my engine.  I basically added a category that extended a cocos2d class.  Without the -all_load flag, I get an unrecognized selector warning.  With it, I get those build errors.  If the all_load flag isn't necessary, then what should I use instead?  From what I read, this is what the ObjC flag is for, but there's apparently a bug that prevents it from working.  Where should I go from here to resolve this?