# The's the meaning of "forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees" for Objective-C linker flag OTHER_LD_FLAGS=-all_load?

Tags: objective-c, linker

I read this Q&A: [What does the -all_load linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-does)

So, does this affect runtime loading? Does final program load unnecessary symbols or only for link time?