# iPhone: Category with property + "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, objective-c-category

First of all I have seen that there are many questions about "unrecognized selector sent to instance" issue.
I have seen few but saw nothing about accessing a defined in category property...

I have a category on UILabel with a property.
The getter and the setter are defined.
Actually I have the same property in 2 different categories (for 2 different classes: UIButton and UILabel).
The problem is that I can access this property for UIButton but not for UILabel.
Once I try to access any method/property in UILabel(text) category it drops the "-[UILabel test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e539f0" exception.

Both categories files are imported.

I have no idea what is the problem.

Here is some code:

```
// UILabel+text.h
@interface UILabel (text)
  - (void)test;
@end

// UILabel+text.m
@implementation UILabel (text)
- (void)test {
  NSLog(@"test");
}
@end

// UIButton+text.h
@interface UIButton (text)
  - (void)test;
@end

// UIButton+text.m
@implementation UIButton (text)
- (void)test {
  NSLog(@"test");// works   
}
@end

// Usage (in UIViewController class) - both elements are defined in XIB
[self.button test];// works
[self.label test];// exception
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I don't have a clue for possible problem...

Thank you.

Michael.

Comment: Interesting... Are they working when created by code? (no XIB)

Comment: Try `[[[UILabel alloc] init] test]` to narrow down the possible source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for fast replies. @Steven has already answered my question. The "UILabel+text.m" file was added to a different target...

Comment: I had this problem because I was missing the -ObjC flag.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Are you using a static library? If so, add all_load to Other Linker Flags.

Are you sure "UILabel+text.m" is in the target?

Comment: That's it!  I always forget the targets issue...  Is there a way to define the new files to be added to all the targets by default?

Comment: That I don't know, Xcode usually seems sense its way in my case. Maybe it defaults to your last selection?

Comment: `-all_load` works most of the time, if you want to know the reason then check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906210/146032

Comment: "all_load" is NOT needed any more (Apple finally fixed that) - but Xcode 4.0 -> 4.6 (and more, maybe) has a nasty bug where categories sometimes disappear from the list of "compile sources", or their headers disappear from the list of "copy headers" in a library build. Thanks!

Comment: I am on Xcode 5.1.1 and I need to add `-all_load`to Other Linker Flags.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue in a project with multiple static frameworks.

Adding `all_load` to Linker Flags did not solve the issue for me!
I had to enable the Build Setting `GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE = YES` so that the category was properly found during runtime.