# Static library give error of objc refrence from

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone i am create application with static library. I am create static library and use this but when we launch the app in device this is give error -objc class refrence. i am not recognize how to solve this

Comment: can you post more detailed info? everything that you can get about error.

Answer (score 0):

have you linked the library in the project settings? check the field library search paths and put the path to the library there. check this for target settings also. Plus add the library to frameworks via right click->add->existing files.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to add the -all_load linker flag to avoid problems with libraries that use categories on externally defined classes.

Here's some more information on it.

[What does the -all_load linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)