# Exception throwing JSON supporting program in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsexception

I downloaded JSON files. I added these files in project directory. But when I am runnig program I am getting an error which is...

> -[__NSCFDictionary
>   JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6003d50
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6003d50'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

I imported header file `#import "JSON/JSON.h"` and I wrote jsocn code in viewDidLoad function which is like below...

```
NSDictionary *requestData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"grio", @"username",
                             @"hellogrio", @"password",
                             nil];

NSString* jsonString = [requestData JSONRepresentation];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: me also in getting same error please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question which JSON implementation you're using, but the error means that you're sending the `JSONRepresentation` message to an `NSDictionary`. The dictionary does not understand the message and raises an exception.

It seems that either you're not using the JSON library correctly or that you have not installed it correctly in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are using [`json-framework`](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). You probably forgot to add `-all_load` to the linker flags. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do) for more details.

Comment: I only added JSON supported files in my project directry by copy and paste. I did not add any frameowrk yet. Should I add ? If yes then please know what and how will i add framework ? I am using Xcode4.

Comment: Should you add -all_load? Yes.