# Problem to trace the route between two points

Tags: ios, cloudmade

i try to trace the route between two points in my iPhone application using cloudmade, the application crashes and i got this report :

```
2011-06-23 17:07:56.153 TopStation[1307:9b03] +[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:headers:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2bdb4c4
2011-06-23 17:07:56.154 TopStation[1307:9b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:headers:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2bdb4c4'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b79919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0298e5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b7b4eb +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02aeb116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02aeacd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   TopStation                          0x00072bbf -[CMRoutingManager findRouteFrom:] + 580
    6   Foundation                          0x0012f2a8 -[NSThread main] + 81
    7   Foundation                          0x0012f234 __NSThread__main__ + 1387
    8   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x910aa7fd _pthread_start + 345
    9   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x910aa682 thread_start + 34
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
Data Formatters unavailable (Error calling dlopen for: "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib": "dlopen(/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib: out of address space")
(gdb)
```

My code is as below :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [RMMapView class];
    TokenManager* tokenManager = [[TokenManager alloc] initWithApikey:@"a53b3323702f42fc8486e24df34f9ac3"];
    _routingManager = [[CMRoutingManager alloc] initWithMapView:mapView tokenManager:tokenManager];
    _routingManager.delegate = self;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D from;
    from.latitude= 53.358311;
    from.longitude=-6.481934;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D to;
    to.latitude=52.657616;
    to.longitude=-8.635254;
    CMRoutingVehicle transport = CMVehicleCar;//CMVehicleWalking or CMVehicleBike
    [_routingManager findRouteFrom:from to:to onVehicle:transport];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This exception

```
 2011-06-23 17:07:56.154 TopStation[1307:9b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:headers:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2bdb4c4'
```

says, that you are sending a message to an class, that doesnt have the method, that fits to it. `+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:headers:]`

my guess: You are not importing a Category on NSArray, that declares and implements `+arrayWithContentsOfURL:headers:`

And make sure you added the linker flags `-ObjC
-all_load`

Comment: i can't add the `-ObjC` and `-all_load`
 flags because i use JSON and that generates an error when compiling.

Comment: than you should investigate on that.

Comment: maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do