# Should I include "-ObjC and -all_load" in Other Linker Flag to all my iOS projects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the -all_load linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)

I see most static library require you to do it, so I add them in all of my projects, seems no side effect in adding this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read about why to use these flags in SO questions:

[What does the -all_load linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)
[Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library)

And then think about if you need to use them or not

Answer (score 17):

There is a side effect: build phase take much time.

-ObjC allow the static library to use objective-c specific stuffs like kvc or categories.

-all_load solve a bug in gcc/llvm, where -ObjC is not correctly used.

Comment: Wow, what a great, to the point summary of Apple's long technical note