# CloudMade geocoding cm_invokeOnMainThread unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, cloudmade

I'm trying to follow the example on http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/iphone-sdk/Create_basic_Local_Search_and_Geocoding_app .

The example from svn provided there runs fine. But when I create my own projects and copy things from there thing gets weird.

I keep on getting the following error:

> 2012-03-29 13:09:57.300 TimGeoCoding[2863:1480b] -[GLViewController
>   cm_invokeOnMainThread]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6877020
>
> 2012-03-29 13:09:57.362 TimGeoCoding[2863:1480b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[GLViewController cm_invokeOnMainThread]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x6877020'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x15a9022 0x1b61cd6 0x15aacbd 0x150fed0 0x150fcb2 0x40a11 0xce04d6
>   0xce0447 0x9627ded9 0x962816de) terminate called throwing an exception

I even created a projects and just started to copy example codes into my code (only fixing the ARC issues and added one line     [RMMapView class] on viewDidLoad ) but it still breaks.
I googled cm_invokeOnMainThread and that one person has the same problem and solved it. But the person didn't post the solution. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turns out that I did not follow the instruction closely as describe here: [How_to_setup_Xcode_to_work_with_CloudMade_iPhone_Library](http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/iphone-sdk/How_to_setup_Xcode_to_work_with_CloudMade_iPhone_Library)

Instead of closely following instructions (which is on Xcode 3), I link the libraries in Target->Build Phases->Link binary with Libraries. This compiles fine, but it's not getting the categories correctly from the static libraries as the result of a problem documented here: [what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do).

So basically I added the linker flags -ObjC -all_load and voila, problem solved.