# Size of static library in iPA

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

How can I faithfully calculate the contribution of a static library to IPA size?

Most information (such as [this QA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html)) I can find is about inspecting the IPA to detect big media. I'm interested in learning which static libraries are contributing more to the IPA.

I looked a the file size of `DerivedData/{App + some id}/Build/Products/Profile-iphoneos/{some id}/lib{Static library}.a` but I suspect this is bigger than the actual size in the IPA.

Comment: I think you can compare the size of two iPAs, the first is use specific static lib, the second is omit the code which reference the static lib.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933948/why-would-the-size-of-the-final-binary-be-so-much-smaller-than-the-size-of-the-s