# Difference between -all_load and -ObjC

Tags: ios, iphone

In what way `-all_load` is different from `-ObjC`. In my project both behave in same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the -all\_load linker flag do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)

Comment: @Amar: Please understand the Question. I m asking the difference between both flags.

Comment: The difference in them is about a bug, which is mentioned in the answer below by Midhun and also in the accepted answer to the question I have linked. Go through the [Apple technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) mentioned in that answer.

Comment: the Apple technical note mentioned in the previous comment now has it's own revision history that states "Removed discussion of workarounds that are unnecessary in Xcode 4 and later. " and there's no discussion of -all_load if there used to be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**-Objc**

This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category.

**-all_load**

For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The workaround is to use the `-all_load` or `-force_load` flags. `-all_load` forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code

Reference [**Building Objective-C static libraries with categories**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1490/_index.html)

Comment: You are right, both flags are used to load all object file. But I m dont know the difference.

Comment: @user1554347: difference is that `For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The workaround is to use the -all_load`. There is no other difference, AFAIK.

Comment: the reference no longer refers to -all_load, apparently because the problem requiring -all_load has been fixed for a while.

Answer (score 7):

From `man ld` ...

```
-all_load   Loads all members of static archive libraries.
-ObjC       Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an Objective-C
              class or category.
```

-ObjC won't draw in all symbols from all static libraries like -all_load will.