# facing trouble when add parse in ios project

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

**I am creating a ios project in which i am adding the parse for push notification, so need to set other linker flag empty,But when i set the other linker flag empty then I get following error when pushing the view controller at run time**

2014-09-06 21:16:04.739 Guess_Funny_Emoji[9100:a0b] +[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2c84c18
2014-09-06 21:16:04.743 Guess_Funny_Emoji[9100:a0b] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2c84c18'

**And when I set the other linker flag by -ObjC then parse error occurred which is as follows**

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**So please help me to resolve this problem**

Comment: try to add all_load in other linker flag

Comment: what is exact keyword for all_load because all_load not found

Comment: Seems like you are using 3rd party static lib, "gad_NegativeOne" is a category added to native class, right? check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do

Comment: I am not getting any help

Comment: I am using only parse and chartboost and admob, nothing else

Answer (score 5):

i had the same error, just make sue you delete ParseFacebookUtils.framework library from your project and keep only ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework

now is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with using Parse and the -ObjC linker flag. You had to import the Facebook SDK, but I don't think you have to anymore with the newest version of Parse. CocoaPods makes it very easy to add the Parse framework along with other libraries. I think all the libraries you've mentioned are available through CocoaPods. [Link](http://cocoapods.org/)

If you'd like additional help setting CocoaPods for all your libraries, let me know.