# iOS static library, cannot access some class methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, unrecognized-selector

I'm building a static library in iOS. after importing that library in my project, I added `-ObjC` in Other linker flags. But when I call the class methods(currently 3 available), 2 of them are being called and executed properly, but the last one is getting this error: `"+[RankConferenceLib joinConferenceWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x5044dc"`.

This is my Header file of library

```
@interface RankConferenceLib : NSObject


+(void)initEnvironment;
+(void)orientationChange;
+(void)joinConferenceWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

in .m file of library

```
+ (void)joinConferenceWithName:(NSString *)name
{
       //....codes
}
```

and in my project I'm calling them

```
- (IBAction)join:(UIButton *)sender {
    [RankConferenceLib joinConferenceWithName:@"User"];
}
```

Please tell me what I'm missing here. This is my first static library. I've searched but could not find any help which is similar as my situation here. Please mention what else you need to know.

Thank you.

Comment: It's very weird, if you can upload the project to github, I'd like to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this and for me it's working fine without any linker flags added.

The only one error possibility is something happened inside the `+ (void)joinConferenceWithName:(NSString *)name`

Write a log inside the `joinConferenceWithName` to printout the parameter `name` and make sure this is calling and the problem is occurring inside that method.

```
+ (void)joinConferenceWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSLog(@"the name is: %@", name);
}
```

**Finally**, make sure that you added the latest modified static library into your project.

You can download the working sample from [here](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/bgr4QwgkyO0CTSP7wCDXsQ)

Comment: Finally i exited my Xcode, cleaned both project, and freshly added the library, then my method was properly found. Thanks @Ramshad

Answer (score 0):

Try Running using the `-all_load` linker flag

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html)

[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)

Comment: Need to provide more explanation. This is not complete answer