# Why Clang++ doesn't run the global object constructor in another static library?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, llvm

We have an library `static_library.a` build by clang++, and there is a file `bar.cpp` include an global object `Foo`.

But when we use the library in App layer Xcode project, but the global object `Foo` constructor doesn't been called. (The global object constructor will do some registration job, and impact the app behavior.)

We think the translation unit are not linked into the executable file.

```
//bar.cpp in static_library.a
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo()
   {
       std::cout << " constructor called" << std::endl;
   }
};

Foo a;
// <------If this function is called in the App layer project, the
// global constructor object will be called. 
Foo* getInstance()  
{
   return &a;
}
```

So does there any flag, which can control this behavior?

Comment: Can you try `-all_load`?

Comment: a better way to control would be to have static variable in getInstance function, whenever the function is called your object will be instantiated

Comment: But there are a lot of global variable in a lot of translation unit, so we cannot list all of them.

Comment: @jtbandes, -all_load works. If you can make it an answer, I will make it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need the `-all_load` linker flag.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do) has more details. You may also be interested in `-ObjC` or `-force_load`.

Comment: I didn't find much information about `-all_load` in the google. Without the `-all_load`, seams the behaviour voliate the C++ standard. So why clang++ have that and make it default?

Comment: @ZijingWu: It's the linker's fault, not clang's, it's because that module isn't referenced from other (needed) modules.