# Swift Project using objective-c framework

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I have a custom framework which is written in objective-c and c++, and now，I try to use the framework in my swift project. I think I configured bridging header file correctly. but still get these errors while compiling the project.

[image]

Comment: Did you setup linker flags correctly if there is any ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless yes，"-ObjC"

Comment: Try adding `-lc++` linker flag.

Comment: @NeverHopeless it works! would you explain that? I googled it, but found nothing.

Comment: OP, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reason why we actually need a linker flag and we get into this problem is defined below in the part taken from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html):

> #### The Linker
>
> When a C program is compiled, each "source file" is turned into an
> "object file" that contains executable functions and static data. The
> linker glues these object files together into a final executable. That
> executable is eventually bundled into an app by Xcode.
>
> When a source file uses something (like a function) defined in another
> file, then an undefined symbol is written into the object file, to
> "stand in" for the missing thing. The linker resolves these symbols by
> pulling in the object files that include definitions of undefined
> symbols when building the final executable.
>
> For example, if main.c uses the function foo(), where foo is defined
> in another file, B.c, then the object file main.o will have an
> unresolved symbol for foo(), and B.o will include an implementation of
> foo(). At link time, B.o will be brought into the final executable, so
> that the code in main.o now references the implementation of foo()
> defined in B.o.
>
> A UNIX static library is just a collection of object files. Normally
> the linker only pulls in an object file from a static library if doing
> so would resolve some undefined symbol. Not pulling in all object
> files reduces the size of the final executable.
>
> #### Objective-C
>
> The dynamic nature of Objective-C complicates things slightly. Because
> the code that implements a method is not determined until the method
> is actually called, Objective-C does not define linker symbols for
> methods. Linker symbols are only defined for classes.
>
> For example, if main.m includes the code [[FooClass alloc]
> initWithBar:nil]; then main.o will contain an undefined symbol for
> FooClass, but no linker symbols for the -initWithBar: method will be
> in main.o.
>
> Since categories are a collection of methods, using a category's
> method does not generate an undefined symbol. This means the linker
> does not know to load an object file defining the category, if the
> class itself is already defined. This causes the same "selector not
> recognized" runtime exception you would see for any unimplemented
> method.
>
> #### The -ObjC Linker Flag
>
> Passing the -ObjC option to the linker causes it to load all members
> of static libraries that implement any Objective-C class or category.
> This will pickup any category method implementations. But it can make
> the resulting executable larger, and may pickup unnecessary objects.
> For this reason it is not on by default.

For the same reason, when we have to include the c++ features we have to add the linker flag for that which is `-lc++` (refer [this url](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)). (AFAIK, if you exlude c++ features -lc++ flag won't be needed)

A short procedure to avoid linker issues is to add `-all_load` (see [what does this flag do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do))

These are my findings for this problem, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot, you make it as clear as crystal.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you use import the framework in your class file if installed via pods. example : import Cloudinary.