# Unrecognized selector sent to class in OAuthCore class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oauth

I have created one library project, in that i am trying to Twitter sharing. But when i tried to on Twitter the application is crashes at following line

```
NSString *_oAuthNonce = [NSString ab_GUID];
```

by error:

> +[NSString ab_GUID]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a09fd8

ab_GUID this method is present in `OAuthCore` class

```
+ (NSString *)ab_GUID
{
    CFUUIDRef u = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    CFStringRef s = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, u);
    CFRelease(u);
    return [(NSString *)s autorelease];
}
```

(My all classes are present in static Library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the `<OAuthCore/OAuth+Additions.h>`? It seems importing `<OAuthCore/OAuthCore.h>` won't include this automatically.

Also make sure [`OAuth+Additions.m`](https://github.com/atebits/OAuthCore/blob/master/OAuth%2BAdditions.m) is compiled into the static library.

Comment: i have imported #import "OAuth+Additions.h"

Comment: <OAuthCore/OAuth+Additions.h> is not found in my class

Comment: Yes  OAuth+Additions.m is compiled but still it crashes

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying that you use a static library:

Make sure you have the -ObjC flag enabled (in the project using the library [same problem treated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932856/calling-method-on-category-included-from-iphone-static-library-causes-nsinvalida)). Or it will not link categories in a static library.

[Objective-C categories in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567498/objective-c-categories-in-static-library)

[image]

Comment: Yes my -ObjC flag is enabled, but still it crashes. There are two static methods in OAuthCore class where application is crashing by error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSString ab_GUID]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a15fd8'